# Apparent non-coherent behaviour between F# and C# when using generics constraints

Tags: c#, f#, generic-constraints

In C#, the following ASP.NET code is valid:

```cs
class A {
    public void WithService<IService, Service>(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) where IService : class where Service : class, IService {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IService, Service>();
    }
}
```

However, the (seemingly) equivalent code in F# is not valid:

```ml
type A() =
    member this.WithService<'IService, 'Service when 'IService: not struct and 'Service: not struct and 'Service :> 'IService>(serviceCollection: IServiceCollection) = 
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<'IService, 'Service>() |> ignore
```

> Error FS0663  This type parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be ''IService when 'IService: not struct'

> Error FS0661  One or more of the explicit class or function type variables for this binding could not be generalized, because they were constrained to other types

> Error FS0698  Invalid constraint: the type used for the constraint is sealed, which means the constraint could only be satisfied by at most one solution

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation in F#, you can't have a subtype constraint on two type parameters, ie `'T :> 'U`. I think there's a language design suggestion to remove this limitation, although I can't find it right now.